# Terraform - Connect cloud armor with ingress load balancer of a gke servicde using Terraform

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-gcp, kubernetes-service

I need some help connecting cloud armor security policies to an ingress load balancer of a gke service. I was able to achieve it with kubernetes yaml through the use of backendconfig in cloud.google.com/v1. However, I am not able to find a replacement in Terraform google provider. Can someone tell me whether building everything purely from Terraform is possible or not?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Google provider, but you can use the [Kubernetes Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs).  Specifically, you would use the [**kubernetes_manifest**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest) resource which allows you to configure any arbitrary Kubernetes resource.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. Due to version reason I don't access to the kubernetes_manifest resource. Is there a way to use the kubernetes provider to create an ingress resource and attach a cloud armour security policy (likely through the google provider) all within Terraform?

Comment: Without using the Kubernetes provider which supports kubernetes_manifest, I'm not sure how you can do this with the Ingress resource.  The Google provider is not focused on the K8S API.  I'll try to update my answer with an alternative, but the option I see is not to use Ingress, but rather to use standalone NEGs with your GKE K8S Services, then use `google_compute_security_policy` to create  a policy and `google_compute_backend_service` to add the policy to the NEG created by the Service.  You can then create a `lb-http` and use the NEG(s) as the backend(s).  Google provider supports this.